# Is there a name for this special type of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

Is there a name for this type of matrix ?
The matrix is always $3\times 3$.

All the $9$ elements are integers.

The determinant of the matrix is $-1$.

Two of the three eigenvalues are reciprocals of one another, and are both positive real numbers.  The third eigenvalue is always $-1 $.

Since none of the eigenvalues is ever zero, the matrix is always nonsingular , and always has an inverse.

The even higher powers of this matrix have determinant $+1 $, and the odd higher powers of this matrix have determinant $-1$.

The even higher powers of this matrix have three eigenvalues, one of those eigenvalues is $+1 $, and the other two eigenvalues are reciprocals of one another.

The odd higher powers of this matrix have three eigenvalues , one of those eigenvalues is $-1 $, and the other two eigenvalues are reciprocals of one another.

Amazingly, the three eigenvectors associated with the three eigenvalues of the matrix, seem to be the same for *for all the higher powers of that matrix*.

Is there a name for this given type of Matrix ?

Comment: Why not call it a *Derek matrix*?

Comment: The "amazing" fact about the eigenvectors you mention is actually true for all matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the things you mention occur for all matrices.

If $Av=\lambda v$, then 
$$
A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda AV=\lambda ^2 v. 
$$
Continuing, you get that $A^nv=\lambda ^n v$.

In general, if $A$ is $n\times n$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues (counting multiplicities) with corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, then $A^m$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1^m,\ldots,\lambda_n^m$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.

Now, going back to your concrete case, you have that $A$ is $3\times 3$. If you require that $-1$ is an eigenvalue, and that $\det A=-1$, then all the other properties you mention follow right away.

Finally, I don't think there's  a specific name for matrices $A\in M_3(\mathbb Z)$ with $\det A=-1$ and $-1$ as an eigenvalue.